# design of this small programe?

Tags: architecture, ooad

[image]**Kindly don't mind my question as it is a little theoretical.**

Last week I gave an interview for job where I was given an assignment to and later they ask question and my design was faulty. So I couldn't get the job. I am sharing my design. Please see it and suggest me where I am wrong and what solution will be a good design of it.

**Problem**
This is a package for a construction company who builds swimming pools. Swimming pool has 2 parts swimming pool surrounding area and pool it self. Both (pool and surrounding area) can be in rectangular or circular shape (please see attached picture) and so there will be 4 possible shapes. Program should calculate shaded area (outer area of pool to concrete).

****Formula** to calculate rectangular area** is Length * Width * 2
**Formula to calculate circular area** is 2 * 2.1718

**My Design**
I made IPool Interface with 2 methods (1) CalculateCircularArea (2) CalculateRectangularArea. Made 2 classes (CircularPool, RectangularPool) implementing IPool interface.

**Question**
What if there are more shapes other then rectangular and circular. Say if there are 100 other shapes, what solution will be considering future prospectus ? Here my design was not good as it was requiring change in interface when ever a new shape comes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The design was already given in the question: A swimming pool **has-a** surrounding and it **has-a** inner pool. The task calls for **composition** rather then inheritance.

With that design we can invent other pool shapes and surroundings and still have swimming pools

```
public interface SwimmingPool {
  Surrounding getSurrounding();
  Pool getPool();
  double getOuterArea();
}

public interface Surrounding extends Shape{
  // some methods for surroundings
}

public interface Pool extends Shape {
  // some methods for pools
}

public interface Shape {
   double getArea();
}
```

Next you create concrete classes for rectangular and circular pools and surroundings use those modules to design swimming pools.

---

Now, we create a concrete swimming pool class:

```
public SwimmingPoolImpl implements SwimmingPool {
 private Surrounding surrounding;
 private Pool pool;
 public SwimmingPoolImpl(Surrounding surrounding, Pool pool) {
   this.surrounding = surrounding;
   this.pool = pool;
 }

 public double getOuterArea() {
   return surrounding.getArea() - pool.getArea();
 }

 public Surrounding getSurrounding() { return surrounding; }
 public Pool getPool() { return pool; }
}
```

Imagine, we have a library of dozens of differen pools and surroundings and we want to create a custom swimmingpool:

```
SwimmingPool customPool = new SwimmingPoolImpl(new OvalSurrounding(), new StarShapedPool());
double pavementArea =  customPool.getOuterArea();
```

That's it. Now we can mainatin a library of different pools and outer areas and use them immediatly to create swimming pools without having to change the swimming pool implementation. That's the benefit of composition.

Comment: Thanks Andreas_D, Kindly guide a little more.
What will be two classes and which class will compose other class ? If more shapes come there can be all combinations of shapes, how to handle it ? How to tell methoed what is outer shape and what is innershape ?

Comment: (the initial tag set contained Java, so I chose Java to visualize the concept)

Comment: thanks Andreas_D,

Pool and Surounding are classes or enum ?

In first block of your code please explain Surrounding getSurrounding();
  Pool getPool(); 

Thanks

Comment: Please accept my aplogies on asking many questions. Please ignore my ignorance.

Is first block of your code acurate with 2nd block of code ?

thanks

Comment: `Pool` and `Surrounding` are interfaces. Imagine some `class OvalSurrounding implements Surrounding`. I've corrected the example, forgot to implement the interface methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas_D, just a last thing please.

"Next you create concrete classes for rectangular and circular pools and surroundings use those modules to design swimming pools". 

Do you mean these classes can be created for any other possible requirements ? What I understood is in current requrimetn we dont need them ? Please guide.

Comment: That was the question: *What if there are more shapes other then rectangular and circular*. Now we need a Rectangles and Circles but we are free to invent new shapes (like oval or star) later without modifying existing code.

Comment: Andreas_D, formula for calculating each shap's (say circular, rectangular, triangular etc) area is different. And outer shape and inner shape can be in any of the shapes. Where I will be putting logic for that.

What if there is a new shape ? How this design will not effected by new shape designs ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8259/discussion-between-haansi-and-andreas-d)

Comment: If we keep Interface Pool and Interface Surounding, we will have to modify them every time a new shape comes ?
or we will have to make many a classes like OvelSurounding, CiccularSuroudning, TriangleSuroudning etc. Is it not better to make ICircle, IRectangular or ITriangular instead of ISurrounding and IPool ?

Answer (score 1):

A typical case for subclassing. Design an abstract class `Shape` with an abstract function `getArea()`, and make a concrete subclass for each possible form you have to deal with.

`Pool` or `SurroundingArea` just need to call `getArea()`, something like this:

```
public class SwimmingPool {
   Shape pool;
   Shape surrounding;

   public double geArea() {return pool.getArea() + surrounding.getArea()}
}

public abstract class Shape {
   public abstract double getArea();
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
   public double getArea() {
     // implementation of area calculation of circles
   }
}

public class Square extends Shape {
   public double getArea() {
     // implementation of area calculation of squares
   }
}

...
```

For pools or surroundings of other shapes, you just need to design another subclass of Shape.

Comment: Thanks user1180720,

"make a concrete subclass for each possible form" mean outer shape or pool ? there can be all possible combinations of outer and inner shapes. How to manage these combinations ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a better design would be to have something like a `IShape` interface that exposes the `getArea()` method. (Or, even better, have it as a property).

This way, both your "objects" implement such interface, and you can calculate the area you want by simply taking the difference between the values of `getArea()`.